# Protect sensitive data on laptop

Tags: ssh, security, encryption

I am planning to take my Ubuntu 14.10 laptop to the computer service for some cleanup. Should I worry about my sensitive data?

Is it possible to steal from system storage device:

- SSH keys
- passwords saved in browsers
- files under `/home` directory

Is [encrypting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) my home directory needed? And how to treat data outside of users' home directories?

Answer (score 2):

With physical access to your computer, it is possible to reset the password and log in to it to steal data. I would just take the hard drive out before bringing the computer in for service, but if you don't want to go this route you should probably encrypt the entire drive.

Comment: Encrypt the entire drive.. Its seems to be a harder way. I'll rather grab it after disassembling

Comment: Depending or where/how you get it serviced, you might be able to get them to take the drive out and give it to you so you are happy they aren't hacking it. Taking it out is probably easier - if you do try encrypting the drive, back it up first.